# Sequelize Association query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, associations

I have two models which are `Services` and `Calendar`.
Users give me a time and I want to get those services which have that time **or don't have any time**. How can I achieve it?

Services Model:

```
    const schema: ModelAttributes<Model<any, any>> = {
        id: {
            type:                   DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey:             true
        },
        name: {
            type:                   DataTypes.STRING(50),
            allowNull:              false
        }
    };

    class Service extends Model{
    };
    Service.init(schema, {
        sequelize:   sequelize,
        modelName:  'Service'
    });
```

Calendar Model:

```
    const newSchema:ModelAttributes<Model<any, any>> = {
        id: {
            type:               DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey:         true
        },
        time: {
            type:               DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        serviceID:  {
            type:               DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references:          {
                model:          Service,
                key:            'id'
            }
        }
    };

    class Calendar extends Model{};
    
    Calendar.init(newSchema, {
        sequelize: sequelize, modelName:  'Calendar'
    });
```

Associations:

```
    Service.hasMany(Calendar, {
        onDelete:   'CASCADE',
        onUpdate:   'CASCADE',
        foreignKey: {
            name:   'serviceID',
        }
    });
    Calendar.belongsTo(Service, {
        onDelete:   'CASCADE',
        onUpdate:   'CASCADE',
        foreignKey: {
            name:    'serviceID'
        }
    });
```

Testing data:

```
    await Service.create({
        id:     0,
        name:   'test'
    })
    await Service.create({
        id:     1,
        name:   'test'
    })
    await Service.create({
        id:     2,
        name:   'test'
    })

    await Calendar.create({
        id:         0,
        serviceID:  0,
        time:  300
    })
    await Calendar.create({
        id:         1,
        serviceID:  0,
        time:  300
    })
    await Calendar.create({
        id:         2,
        serviceID:  1,
        time:  400
    })
```

**Now assume that I wanna to get services which have time equal to `300` or don't have any time**. My current query is as below:

```
let result = await Service.findAndCountAll({
        where: {
            name:       'test'
        },
        include:                    [
        {
            model:                  Calendar,
            duplicating:            false,
            where:                  {
                time:          300 
            },
            required:               false
        }],
        offset:                     0,
        limit:                      10,
        distinct:                   true
    });
```

**Expected OUTPUT:**
I want to get only the both `0` and `2` services in output.

**Current OUTPUT:**
It gives me all services (including service with `1` id):

```
{
  id: 0,
  name: 'test',
  createdAt: 2022-06-21T13:11:11.730Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-06-21T13:11:11.730Z,
  Calendars: [
    {
      id: 0,
      time: 300,
      serviceID: 0,
      createdAt: 2022-06-21T13:11:11.806Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-06-21T13:11:11.806Z
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      time: 300,
      serviceID: 0,
      createdAt: 2022-06-21T13:11:11.828Z,
      updatedAt: 2022-06-21T13:11:11.828Z
    }
  ]
}
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'test',
  createdAt: 2022-06-21T13:11:11.771Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-06-21T13:11:11.771Z,
  Calendars: []
}
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'test',
  createdAt: 2022-06-21T13:11:11.783Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-06-21T13:11:11.783Z,
  Calendars: []
}
```

Comment: Remove `required: false`, it makes a left outer join.

Comment: @8bitIcon inner join results in loss of services without any Calendar. But I need them in output.

Comment: Can you use an OR operator on the where clause? https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators

Comment: @boc4life Yes I can but what's the point?

Comment: Well the query that you're looking to generate is WHERE time = X OR time IS NULL. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, but it seems relatively straightforward why an OR operator is what you want.